# How to get GUI-selected folder's absolute path in electron, node.js, or html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I need the user to be able to open a file selector from within the app, select a directory, and then I need the full path of that directory. I am building an electron app in node.js, running on windows, and jquery is welcome if that helps. I don't care if the solution is node-specific or if it's just some html and javascript. I know how to get the name of a directory, but I need the full path of the directory.

Comment: What? I'm asking how to do it. What kind of question should I ask? I don't expect anyone to write all of my code for me, I am asking more knowledgeable people how to do something that I don't know how to. That is one of the main purposes of stack overflow isn't it?

Comment: That is purpose yes, but still this question doesn't include any information what you were searching, attempt, and why it failed. Without those, answer may either easily duplicate or redundant for you which won't be great help for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Electron [`showOpenDialog`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options-callback) method on the `dialog` API.

```
const { dialog } = require('electron')
const pathArray = dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openDirectory']}))
```

This can be called from the renderer process using `remote`

```
const { remote } = require('electron')
const pathArray = remote.dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openDirectory']}))
```